# With Jenkins is there a way to add custom information to a build which can then be read via API?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I'd like to have some information available in the build info you get via API (e.g. https://jenkins-server/job/some-job/191/api/json?depth=0)

Next to the job parameters provided to the build you get all sorts of information about a specific build, like status, duration, artifacts, etc.

Now - is it possible to add *custom* information to this build at build time (i.e. programmatically)?

Something like

```
currentBuild.metaInfo = [
    foo: "bar",
    magicHash: calculateMagicHash(),
]
```

The closest thing I know would be to write a file and put it into the build artifacts. While this might be an option, I'd prefer a fast 'lightweight' solution which does not pollute the artifacts and comes with the `buildInfo` (which I have to fetch anyway).

The `actions` collection looks promising, since it seems to have a variable number of arbitrary elements. Can I modify it during build time?

Comment: Tempering with the builds actions is not that simple. For an easy solution you can use the Description of each build to Inject metadata (in a predetermined format) and then read it via the API.